# What might be the probable reason for SIG 7 to occur?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have an Erlang & C application being developed on an embedded platform, in which the micro-controller(Freescale MPC8308) interacts with a telecom mapper chip(PMC 5426) which is  interfaced via a PCIe bus. The micro-controller regularly interacts with the mapper device chip to query some monitoring parameters like alarm and performance every 1 second.

The problem here is after running for about 3-4 hours, I get an error thrown from the kernel complaining about a SIG 7(SIGBUS) which means

### An attempt was made to access memory incorrectly. This can be caused by alignment errors in memory access etc.

- Where do I look for errors to debug this problem, in the PCIe kernel driver or in the application?
- Is it possible to handle this error so that the "kernel Oops" doesn't occur?
- How to unload a tainted kernel module so that it can be reloaded again?

The kernel throws the error such as:

```
Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#1]
MPC830x RDB
Modules linked in: hyphy_pcie mpc_cs2_adbus_access_module
NIP: cd1da524 LR: cd1da4cc CTR: 00000000
REGS: c71f5d80 TRAP: 0200   Not tainted  (2.6.29.6-rt23)
MSR: 00041000 <ME>  CR: 44000442  XER: 00000000
TASK = c794e960[1656] 'hyphy_cnode' THREAD: c71f4000
GPR00: 00000000 c71f5e30 c794e960 cd1dadec 00000000 00000000 c71f5eb4 00000000
GPR08: 04921d4c d2121d4c 00000004 ffffffff 04921d50 10202a5c 00000000 00000000
GPR16: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000ffff 04921d4c 4982d5dc c71f5f28 c71f5e38
GPR24: cd1e0000 cd1e0000 00000004 cd1e0000 00000001 04921d4c 00000000 00000000
Call Trace:
[c71f5ef0] [c00761f4] 0xc00761f4
[c71f5f10] [c0076674] 0xc0076674
[c71f5f40] [c001141c] 0xc001141c
--- Exception: c01 at 0xffa0014
    LR = 0xff9fff0
Instruction dump:
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX 7ffdfb78 XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX 48000030
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX 7d69fc2c XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX 7d7fb92e
---[ end trace 82414d2c955335e9 ]---

Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#2]
MPC830x RDB
Modules linked in: hyphy_pcie mpc_cs2_adbus_access_module
NIP: cd1da524 LR: cd1da4cc CTR: 00000000
REGS: c719fd80 TRAP: 0200   Tainted: G      D     (2.6.29.6-rt23)
MSR: 00049030 <EE,ME,IR,DR>  CR: 48000422  XER: 00000000
TASK = c78784d0[1688] 'hyphy_cnode' THREAD: c719e000
GPR00: 00000000 c719fe30 c78784d0 cd1dadec 00000000 00000000 c719feb4 00000000
GPR08: 04960200 d2160200 00000004 00000000 04960204 10202a5c 00000077 00000077
GPR16: 00000073 00000066 00000067 10013430 04960200 bf93cf8c c719ff28 c719fe38
GPR24: cd1e0000 cd1e0000 00000004 cd1e0000 00000001 04960200 00000000 00000000
Call Trace:
[c719fe30] [c03ceb80] 0xc03ceb80 (unreliable)
[c719fef0] [c00761f4] 0xc00761f4
[c719ff10] [c0076674] 0xc0076674
[c719ff40] [c001141c] 0xc001141c
--- Exception: c01 at 0xff9ff90
    LR = 0xffb622c
Instruction dump:
419e0168 575cf0bf 41820094 7ffdfb78 3bc00000 3f60cd1e 3f20cd1e 48000030
813bb3a0 7d3d4a14 7c0004ac 7d69fc2c <0c0b0000> 4c00012c 381e0001 7d7fb92e
---[ end trace 82414d2c955335ea ]---
4

Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#3]
MPC830x RDB
Modules linked in: hyphy_pcie mpc_cs2_adbus_access_module
NIP: cd1da524 LR: cd1da4cc CTR: 00000000
REGS: c7205d80 TRAP: 0200   Tainted: G      D     (2.6.29.6-rt23)
MSR: 00049030 <EE,ME,IR,DR>  CR: 48000422  XER: 00000000
TASK = c78df980[1692] 'hyphy_cnode' THREAD: c7204000
GPR00: 00000000 c7205e30 c78df980 cd1dadec 00000000 00000000 c7205eb4 00000000
GPR08: 04960200 d2160200 00000004 00000000 04960204 10202a5c 00000077 00000077
GPR16: 00000073 00000066 00000067 10013430 04960200 bfc2ef8c c7205f28 c7205e38
GPR24: cd1e0000 cd1e0000 00000004 cd1e0000 00000001 04960200 00000000 00000000
Call Trace:
[c7205e30] [c03ceb80] 0xc03ceb80 (unreliable)
[c7205ef0] [c00761f4] 0xc00761f4
[c7205f10] [c0076674] 0xc0076674
[c7205f40] [c001141c] 0xc001141c
--- Exception: c01 at 0xff9ff90
    LR = 0xffb622c
Instruction dump:
419e0168 575cf0bf 41820094 7ffdfb78 3bc00000 3f60cd1e 3f20cd1e 48000030
813bb3a0 7d3d4a14 7c0004ac 7d69fc2c <0c0b0000> 4c00012c 381e0001 7d7fb92e
---[ end trace 82414d2c955335eb ]---
...
Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#4]
MPC830x RDB
Modules linked in: hyphy_pcie mpc_cs2_adbus_access_module
NIP: cd1da524 LR: cd1da4cc CTR: 00000000
REGS: c71cbd80 TRAP: 0200   Tainted: G      D     (2.6.29.6-rt23)
MSR: 00049030 <EE,ME,IR,DR>  CR: 48000422  XER: 00000000
TASK = c794e960[1696] 'hyphy_cnode' THREAD: c71ca000
GPR00: 00000000 c71cbe30 c794e960 cd1dadec 00000000 00000000 c71cbeb4 00000000
GPR08: 04960200 d2160200 00000004 00000000 04960204 10202a5c 00000077 00000077
GPR16: 00000073 00000066 00000067 10013430 04960200 bf8d3f8c c71cbf28 c71cbe38
GPR24: cd1e0000 cd1e0000 00000004 cd1e0000 00000001 04960200 00000000 00000000
Call Trace:
[c71cbe30] [c03ceb80] 0xc03ceb80 (unreliable)
[c71cbef0] [c00761f4] 0xc00761f4
[c71cbf10] [c0076674] 0xc0076674
[c71cbf40] [c001141c] 0xc001141c
--- Exception: c01 at 0xff9ff90
    LR = 0xffb622c
Instruction dump:
419e0168 575cf0bf 41820094 7ffdfb78 3bc00000 3f60cd1e 3f20cd1e 48000030
813bb3a0 7d3d4a14 7c0004ac 7d69fc2c <0c0b0000> 4c00012c 381e0001 7d7fb92e
---[ end trace 82414d2c955335ec ]---
```

Comment: As this is a "Kernel Oops", it is a **kernel** who is responsible for it. `Is it possible to handle this error so that the "kernel Oops" doesn't occur?` - **Fix** the error. Really, what else do you expect? After the Oops kernel module is rarely can be unloaded.

Comment: as per Oops `hyphy_pcie mpc_cs2_adbus_access_module` these are the modules it causing SIG 7